# Automatic conversion of `for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++)` to enhanced for / for-each loops? Find enhance-able for loops?

Tags: java, regex, foreach

I just refactored a small part of a large project grown over years to have some methods accept a `Collection` where previously a `List` was required. for this, I had to rewrite some code à la

```
for (int i=0; i < someList.size(); i++) {
    SomeType element = someList.get(i);
    someMethod(element);
    // ... more code not using i
    // or sometimes just: someMethod(/*other args */ someList.get(i));
}
```

to

```
for (SomeType element: someList) {
    someMethod(element);
    // ... more code not using i
}
```

Since there are probably many more occurrences of this pattern, I wonder whether there is a way to automatically convert the old-style loop to the enhanced one, or at least report the loops that can be converted? ([`pmd:AvoidArrayLoops`](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/optimizations.html#AvoidArrayLoops) - we are using Sonar for code analysis - does something similar for arrays, but with a few false positives)

I could even imagine a regular expression might help, but do not consider myself well-versed enough to handle the part of establishing that the loop variable is only used in a `get` method of the list whose size is checked in the termination expression.

Comment: I wouldn't waste time to do that. `Collection.size()` is defined, `get()` is not, the compiler will find the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse:

- Menu `Window > Preferences`, `Java > Code Style > Clean Up`.
- Edit the profile
- Tab `Code Style`
- `Control statements > Convert for loops to enhanced`
- Save (probably creating a new profile) and close the preferences
- Create a Java project with your sources
- Context menu of the source folder, `Source > Clean Up...`

Comment: Ah...I feel stupid now. ;-) I vaguely remembered having seen such a feature somewhere, but did not suspect it to be right before my eyes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is able to do this with its *Clean Up* feature.

Select the project you try to change. From the menu *Source* choose *Clean Up...* and the *next* to review the changes.

You will have to configure loop enhancing under *code style*.